# jquery get selected option value giving undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get selected option value from post format Wordpress dashboard. But when I am trying to get option value in alert also in the console, it is giving me undefined. Is there anywhere I am doing wrong?

```
(function ($){
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var conceptName = $('#post-format-selector-0 ').find("option:selected").val();

        var values = $('#post-format-selector-0 :selected').val();

        alert(conceptName);

        console.log(values);

    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

screenshot1

[image]

screenshot2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `children()` function and pass your `selector`

```
var conceptName = $('#post-format-selector-0 ').children("option:selected").val();
```

take a lock at this [script](https://jsfiddle.net/kx82auq6/1/)

```
(function ($){
"use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {
       alert( "val:" + $('#post-format-selector-0 ').val());
       alert( "find:" + $('#post-format-selector-0 ').find("option:selected").val());
       alert( "children:" + $('#post-format-selector-0 ').children("option:selected").val());
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: sorry for that, I think we have another issue here can you edit your question and add  more clarification

Comment: it is giving alert undefined value before the whole page load

Comment: what clarification do you need?

Comment: make a screenshot or get the error message here, please

Comment: hello, i have added two screenshot

Comment: check the updated answer, after this if it does not work, you should check the jquery itself,

Comment: what can be the problem, I have enqueued jquery script manually without WordPress jquery, but giving result undefined

Answer (score 0):

To get value of selected option

`var conceptName = $('#post-format-selector-0 option:selected').val();`

To get text of selected option

`var conceptName = $('#post-format-selector-0 option:selected').text();`

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `.val()` on the `select` element:

```js
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('pre').html($('#demo').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="demo">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>


<button>Get value</button>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: You're missing the point. You can't use `$('option:selected').val()`, you have to use `$(select).val()`.  I used a button so you can see it working in the snippet.